# 301 Redirect not working properly in Global.asax file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I have few redirects defines in my global.asax file. one example is as below.

All the redirect work properly but when i tried to add a new redirect that is the first one  defined in below example it is not working for some reason.

I enter this as a sample url in browser `http://website.com/Page.aspx?PageId=15`

```
//This doesn't work
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://website.com/Page.aspx?PageId=15"))
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://website.com/Page.aspx?PageId=15", "http://website.com/contact.aspx?PageId=15&Language=en-US"));
    }

//This  work s
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://website.com/news"))
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://website.com/news", "http://website.com/news.aspx?PageId=25&Language=en-US"));
    }
```

other url redirect properly like `http://website.com/news` `http://website.com/about-us` etc..

Comment: what you mean by not working where it is redirecting currently?

Comment: I mean if i enter url `http://website.com/Page.aspx?PageId=15` then it should redirect to  `http://website.com/contact.aspx?PageId=15&Language=en-US` rather it just executes the URL entered without redirecting ...`http://website.com/Page.aspx?PageId=15`

Comment: make sure that string exists complete in url otherwise it should work

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, my url is fine and besides that i am using .`Contains` which should match with url anyways. rather than using `.Equal()`. I tried different scenarios, but nothing seems to work. Logically i don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: that is what i am saying

Answer (score 3):

You're setting your Url to ToLower, but you're comparing it to a Url with uppercase letters.

Try setting the string literal that you're comparing your Url with to lowercase letters as well:

```
Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://website.com/page.aspx?pageid=15")
```

Comment: did not get your point i am using `Request.Url.ToString().ToLower()` in both statments. I am using .`ToLower()` as using can type in url in any form small, caps, sentenceCase etc..

Comment: You misunderstand me. The string you're comparing your Url to has uppercase characters. Contains is case sensitive. You're Setting your Url ToLower(), but you're comparing it to something with Uppercase letters in it. So your Url tries to compare page.aspx with Page.aspx, but since it's case-sensitive comparison, it can't match them since your P is a different case in both strings.

Comment: +1. @KnowledgeSeeker you are using ToLower, which will lowercase the URL, yet you are  comparing it to a string that is not loweracse, so it will never be true. The 2nd statement works because you are comparing it to an all lowercase string.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker If my answer solved your problem, please accept it to let the community know it worked for you.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs, My apology, i misunderstood you initially. my approach was wrong very basic mistake on my part..

Answer (score 0):

Use an `else if` instead two `if` conditions.